# Как сделать правильное объединение таблицы в базе mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, sql-server, запрос

Есть сделанные два запроса в базу и склеенные в один, но вот не получается его сгруппировать так чтобы не выкидывало часть данных.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И получить после группировки такой результат чтобы были в колонке potr и kolob и пустые значения и заполненные.

[image: результат]

```
 BEGIN

/*
SELECT DISTINCT reg1,grafik, potr,kolob 
FROM
(*/

 SELECT r.id_reg AS idreg,r.regnames AS reg1,r.subord AS subr, r.subordend AS sebr,
(SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM kartosn k WHERE  k.obdate > 2006-01-01  AND k.subord>=subr AND k.subord<sebr ) AS grafik,
r.test AS potr,r.test AS kolob

 FROM region r 
 WHERE r.id_reg>1 AND r.id_reg<>10  AND r.id_reg<>20 AND r.id_reg<>30 AND r.id_reg<>40 AND r.id_reg<>12 AND r.id_reg<>13


 UNION

SELECT idreg, reg1,
(SELECT r.test FROM region r WHERE r.id_reg=1 ) AS t2,
(SELECT r.test FROM region r WHERE r.id_reg=1 ) AS t1,
(SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM kartosn k WHERE  k.obdate > 2006-01-01  AND k.subord>=subr AND k.subord<sebr ) AS grafik,
 (SELECT COUNT( idreg )) AS potr,
(SELECT (SUM(ografik)+SUM(cgrafik)) FROM region r WHERE idreg=r.id_reg ) AS kolob
FROM (
SELECT   k.obdate, k.kartel_id as id,r.id_reg AS idreg, r.regnames AS reg1, r.subord AS subr ,r.subordend AS sebr,
(SELECT COUNT( * ) AS N FROM objects o WHERE ografik=1 AND o.kartel_id =id) AS ografik,       
(SELECT COUNT( * ) AS M FROM ctp WHERE `cgrafik` =1 AND kartel_id =  id) as cgrafik,      
(SELECT DATE_FORMAT( o.pasobdate, "%d.%m.%Y" ) FROM ozp o WHERE o.kartel_id = id AND o.pasobdate>"0000-00-00" ) AS pasobdate 
FROM kartosn k, `region` r, auth a WHERE k.obdate > "2009-01-01" AND k.obdate <date_ob                
AND( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ozp o WHERE o.kartel_id = k.kartel_id  AND o.pasobdate>"0000-00-00")<>1               
AND a.`subord` = k.`subord` AND k.`subord`=r.`subord`  
 GROUP BY id  ORDER BY reg1
 ) AS ff GROUP BY reg1

 /*
 )AS tyyyyy

 ORDER BY reg1
*/

 ;
END
```

Comment: Вы бы хоть сами запросы привели. А то совершенно не ясно что вы называете "двумя запросами склеенными в один", склеенными чем, клеем момент, БФ-2 или может все таки union, а может этот какой то хитрый join, поди угадай...

Comment: Запросы склеены тупо UNION

Comment: Ну так что бы при union они давали первый результат надо сильно постараться, явно написать NULL колонки в запросах. может просто стоит задать в запросах правильные списки выводимых колонок, что бы выдавали только нужные данные и в нужных колонках

Comment: Колонки  potr и kolob в первом запросе специально создались пустыми чтобы при объединении в них записать данные со второго запроса

Comment: Кажется начинаю понимать... так сделайте group by всего этого и возьмите скажем max() от колонок

Comment: Вы бы дописали свой запрос и ожидаемый результат. А то пока ваш вопрос выглядит "мне лень думать, решите за меня". При этом еще приходится угадывать, а что Вы вообще хотите увидеть в результате

Comment: Результат который нужно получить на втором фото,

Comment: Вот пока как не пытался через GOUP BY и DISTINCT не могу прейти к нужному результату, либо убирает за много reg и оставляет potr и kolob или наоборот reg1 приводит в порядок а potr и kolob не дописывает

Comment: Поэтому может у кого то больше опыта работы с sql может покажет как сделать запрос с группировкой правильно.

Comment: Что бы это сделать надо как минимум видеть ваш исходный запрос, а вы наотрез отказываетесь его написать в вопросе ... вообще я уже сказал что нужно сделать group by и к колонкам применить max()

Comment: Добавил сам запрос

Comment: Мда, могли бы конечно сократить до минимально необходимого ... в общем вы пробовали `select id_reg, reg1, max(grafic) as grafic, max(potr) port, max(kolob) kloob from (ваш-запрос) A group by id_reg, reg1` ?  И кстати, вот этим `SELECT r.test FROM region r WHERE r.id_reg=1` вы NULL получаете ? может написать просто `NULL as t2` ...

Comment: Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause ругается на данную ошибку, да в SELECT r.test FROM region r WHERE r.id_reg=1 я выбираю Null просто не знал как по другому

Comment: А вы group by в конце то написали ? ошибка говорит о том, что вы group by не написали ...

Comment: Спасибо. Работает

Answer (score 1):

```
select id_reg, reg1, max(grafic) as grafic, max(potr) port, max(kolob) kloob
  from (
        ваш-большой-запрос
       ) A
 group by id_reg, reg1
```

P.S. (немного офтопик): могу предложить следующую оптимизацию *текста* запроса:

1. `r.id_reg>1 AND r.id_reg<>10  AND r.id_reg<>20 ...` переписать как `r.id_reg>1 AND r.id_reg not in(10,20,30,40,12,13)` - просто короче и нагляднее.
2. Начало второй части основного запроса упростить так:

   ```
   SELECT idreg, reg1,
          NULL AS t2, NULL AS t1,
          (SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM kartosn k WHERE  k.obdate > 2006-01-01  AND k.subord>=subr AND k.subord<sebr ) AS grafik,
          COUNT(idreg) AS potr,
          SUM(ografik)+SUM(cgrafik) AS kolob
   ```
3. В самом глубоком подзапросе второй части выбираются такие колонки как subr, sebr, pasobdate (отдельным подзапросом), но нигде далее они не используются. можно их убрать, если конечно они не понадобятся во внешних слоях запроса в будущем.

Comment: Попробуйте вместо UNION написать UNION ALL